# .htaccess Rewrite 403 Forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

I have a .htaccess rule for get content from the file partnerzy.php when user types:

https://example.com/partnerzy
and
https://example.com/partnerzy/

at address field. My .htaccess contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /partnerzy
RewriteRule partnerzy.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /partnerzy/
RewriteRule ^(.*) partnerzy.php [NC]
```

The rule works on different service, but for my site I get

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this document.
```

Why it doesn't works ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax issue in your first `RewriteRule`.

Replace all of your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(partnerzy)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for smart rule. On different host both rules works. But ... on the same host yours and my rule doesn't work. I've asked my admin whats wrong.

Comment: .htaccess is located at ROOT folder (https://example.com/.htaccess). Other comands force https urls.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask my admin. But I can't get right base for other relative links on the site. I've put RewriteBase / but urls goes to https://example.com/partnerzy/url.php, not to https://example.com/url.php: . How to provide right base ?

Comment: Thank you very much :), till now I've used full page address at `<base href="http://example.com"; />` and absolute paths for html/js/css files. Your way is much better.

Comment: I've found the reason ... by myself. There was a folder with the same name like php filename (partnerzy/) and then apache says: 403 Forbidden. In that case Apache doesn't know what to load: php file conent or index.(*) from the folder and says forbidden.

Comment: I haven't a `.htaccess` file at partnerzy/ folder. Perhaps It's guides Apache to do something but I've just catch forbidden disappears without folder. What rules at `.htaccess` provide right responde ?

Comment: Exactly same rule as shown above works for me with a folder and php file existing with same name.

Comment: I steel wait for my admin reply ... but after directory remove my rule works properly. What is the syntax error you write ?

Comment: I mean your reply at your answer "You have a syntax issue in your first RewriteRule".

Comment: Sorry, your syntax issue is here: `RewriteRule partnerzy.php [NC]` since there is no separate source pattern and target in this.

Comment: My admin helped me with this issue. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The server contains the same folder name like rewrite result `/partnerzy/`.
Apache doesn't know what to load: `partnerzy/` content from `partnerzy.php` (rewrite rule) or `partnerzy/index.(*)` and says: `403 Forbidden`

There are two ways to solve issue:

- make `partnerzy/.htaccess` with `Options +DirList` rule,
- change dir name `partnerzy` to another

Then there is no colision with 403 Forbidden

Comment: No, It cannot be reproduced. That won't cause Apache to return `403`, there is something else in Apache config causing `403`